# shared_ptr returning an interface

Tags: inheritance, interface, c++11, shared-ptr

So I'm hacking away at my code trying to turn it in to some half-decent C++0x code using GCC 4.5..

```
shared_ptr<IEngineLayer*> createEngineLayer(void)
{
    try
    {
        CEngineLayer* engine = new CEngineLayer;
        IEngineLayer* interface = dynamic_cast<IEngineLayer*>(engine);

        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer*>(interface);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        // Unable to allocate enough memory for the engine layer.
        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer*>();
    }
}
```

And I get this..

> shared_ptr_base.h:545:65: error: cannot convert ‘DEngine::IEngineLayer*’ to ‘DEngine::IEngineLayer**’ in initialization

How can I fix this?

(Also, as a side note, will shared_ptr destroy both the interface and the CEngineLayer when nobody is using it anymore?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `shared_ptr<T>` models a pointer to `T`, a `shared_ptr<T *>` models a pointer to pointer to `T`.

Assuming that `CEngineLayer` is a `IEngineLayer`, you could change your code to :

```
shared_ptr<IEngineLayer> createEngineLayer()
{
    try
    {
        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>(new CEngineLayer);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        // Unable to allocate enough memory for the engine layer.
        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>();
    }
}
```

Also note that a 'derived to base' conversion does not require an explicit cast : if `CEngineLayer` inherits publicly from `IEngineLayer`, a pointer to `CEngineLayer` can be implicitly converted to a pointer to `IEngineLayer`.

> Also, as a side note, will shared_ptr
>   destroy both the interface and the
>   CEngineLayer when nobody is using it
>   anymore?

There is a single object whose type is `CEngineLayer` which, if the destructor in `IEngineLayer` is virtual (and it should be), will be correctly destroyed when the reference count reaches 0.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda followed along the lines of other STD containers like vector<object*> rather than remember that its a pointer. And thank you for that single object info.

Answer (score 2):

Return a `shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>` instead.

The cast isn't needed either:

```
shared_ptr<IEngineLayer> createEngineLayer()
{
    try
    {
        CEngineLayer* engine = new CEngineLayer;

        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>(engine);
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        // Unable to allocate enough memory for the engine layer.
        return shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use make_shared, which is from a performance perspective better:

```
std::shared_ptr<IEngineLayer> createEngineLayer(void)
{
    return std::make_shared<CEngineLayer>();
}
```

Also be are that the following code creates a memory leak:

```
std::shared_ptr<IEngineLayer> createEngineLayer(void)
{
    IEngineLayer* pInterface = new CEngineLayer;

    return std::shared_ptr<IEngineLayer>(pInterface);
}
```

In this case the shared_ptr deletes an IEngineLayer and not CEngineLayer